# AVI capture program in visual basic .net stops working with call backs enabled during recording

Tags: vb.net, video, callback, delegates

I have written a visual basic .net desktop application using avicap32.dll calls.
This works completely as expected until I introduce callbacks **whilst recording video**.
Callbacks are enabled prior to recording and disabled after recording is finished and the output file written.

Recording is done with the CAPTUREPARMS fYield parameter set to 1. The recording is therefore **captured as a separate background thread**.

The application may record with working callbacks, multiple times, however at some point I get the dreaded "The Application is in Break Mode".
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Debug output: Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Unknown Module.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

- Does this show that it is an external exception and if so to what?
- Why should the callback work and then stop?
- Have I set up the callbacks correctly and in the best way?

After working on this extensively I am stuck!

I am using :
Declare Function SendMessageP Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As ErrorCall) As Integer

in place of the old:
Declare Function SendMessageP Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

where lparam was sent the **addressof** the callback routine

Relevant code:

```
dim UseEvents as Boolean
' if UseEvents = True then write to rich text box using events and delegates

Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Boolean, ByRef lParam As Integer) As Boolean

Declare Function SendMessageP Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As ErrorCall) As Integer

    'Define the public signature of our callback procedure... 
    Public Delegate Sub ErrorCall(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal iID As Integer, ByVal ipstrStatusText As String)

    Private Sub MyErrorCallback(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal iID As Integer, ByVal ipstrStatusText As String)   ' IDS_CAP_DRIVER_ERROR = 418       '/* Driver specific error message */ 
        If iID = 0 Then Exit Sub

        If isRecording Then
            If UseEvents Then
                ' have to use a delegate to write to the info box
                RaiseEvent GotCallback(Me, "Callback Error " + iID.ToString() + ": " + ipstrStatusText, Color.Orange)
            Else
                ' record in a global variable
                LastError = "Callback Error " + iID.ToString() + ": " + ipstrStatusText
            End If
        Else
            showme("Callback Error " + iID.ToString() + ": " + ipstrStatusText, Color.Orange)
        End If
    End Sub


    Declare Function SendMessagePS Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As StatusCall) As Integer

    'Define the signature of our callback procedure... 
    Public Delegate Sub StatusCall(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal iID As Integer, ByVal ipstrStatusText As String)

    Private Sub MyStatusCallback(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal iID As Integer, ByVal ipstrStatusText As String)
        If iID = 0 Then Exit Sub
        If isRecording Then
            If iID = 511 Or iID = 512 Then      ' show only the end of recording fps, lost frames and audio details
                If UseEvents Then
                    ' have to use a delegate to write to the info box
                    RaiseEvent GotCallback(Me, ipstrStatusText, Color.BlueViolet)
                Else
                    ' Record in a global variable
                    LastStatus = ipstrStatusText
                    'Debug.Print("Status " + iID.ToString() + ": " + ipstrStatusText)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            showme("Status " + iID.ToString() + ": " + ipstrStatusText, Color.BlueViolet)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Const WM_CAP As Short = &H400S
    Public Const WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_ERROR = WM_CAP + 2
    Public Const WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_STATUS = WM_CAP + 3

' Call back initialisation:
dim CbE,CbS as boolean
' showme is a helper routine to write to a rich text box

    Private Sub SetCallBacks()
        On Error Resume Next
        CbE = SendMessageP(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_ERROR, 0, AddressOf MyErrorCallback)
        showme("Set Error callback " + CbE.ToString())

        CbS = SendMessagePS(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_STATUS, 0, AddressOf MyStatusCallback)
        showme("Set Status callback " + CbS.ToString())

        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopCallbacks()
        Dim retval As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
        showme("")
        If CbE Then
            retval = SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_ERROR, 0, vbNull)
            showme("Set Error Callback off " + Str(retval))
            CbE = False
        End If
        If CbS Then
            retval = SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_STATUS, 0, vbNull)
            showme("Set Status Callback off " + Str(retval))
            CbS = False
        End If

        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub
```

I get the same crash if I set UseEvents to False and transfer the feedback messages to global variables.

I have also tried passing the messages as pointers with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more reading I believe I have a solution.

The application is now stable.

The parameter passed as the address of the call back function was being lost.
This appears to be as a result of having to declare the delegate as public.

I have set up private addresses for the callbacks to maintain a reference to the callback delegate:

```
    Private MyErrorAddress As New ErrorCall(AddressOf MyErrorCallback)
    Private MyStatusAddress As New StatusCall(AddressOf MyStatusCallback)
```

The callback setup subroutine is now

```
Private Sub SetCallBacks()
  On Error Resume Next
  CbE = SendMessageP(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_ERROR, 0, MyErrorAddress)     
  CbS = SendMessagePS(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_CALLBACK_STATUS, 0, MyStatusAddress)  
  Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```

This may help others who wish to register callbacks for background threads.